# How to remove a photo in modern CV latex format?

Tags: moderncv

I have been trying to get rid of the picture in the modernCV latex template (Classic Style) without changing anything else (just shifting the details to the right). Can somebody suggest how to do that ?

Here is a link to overleaf:  https://www.overleaf.com/8001856rzvwdqvwjwht#/28211566/

The moderncvstyleclassic.sty file has the code that deals with the photo.

Comment: You need to provide a template (minimal example) we can work with. [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) has many *styles*, and a solution would depend on that. Perhaps [`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) would work?

Comment: In moderncv classic you can simply uncomment the line with the photo, search for `photo...`

Comment: @Werner I am using the classic style.

Comment: @ChristophS I tried commenting out the photo section in the classicstyle file but that shifts the details (email, address etc. to the line below)

Comment: It does not render in my case. I get: `./moderncvstylecasual.sty:25: Runaway argument? {\recomputecvlengths \newbox {\makecvtitledetailsbox }\savebox {\makecvtitledet ailsbox \ETC. File ended while scanning use of \@argdef. <inserted text> \par l.25`

Comment: Keep the photo command but define a file with pure white?  Scale the image to 0pt?

Comment: If I try to compile the code locally, I get a `Missing \begin{document}. \homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{s` error. Uncommenting the line defining the homepage, and then commenting/uncommenting the photo seems to work as expected

Comment: @Wiebke Homepage probably has to be wrapped in url from the hyperlink package, otherwise you will get complains about illegal chars